# benefit of image LinearTransform Layer for semantic segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I'm investigating UNet implementation used to segment retinal vessels [Project Here](https://github.com/DeepTrial/Retina-VesselNet).

I've found a layer called **LinearTransform** (*implementation provided below*) that is used as preprocessing step for RGB images before passing them to UNet network for semantic segmentation.

can anybody tell the benefit for using it?

```py
class LinearTransform(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, patch_size,name="LinearTransform"):
    super(LinearTransform, self).__init__(self,name=name)

    self.conv_r=Conv2D(1,kernel_size=3,strides=1,padding='same',use_bias=False)
    self.conv_g=Conv2D(1,kernel_size=3,strides=1,padding='same',use_bias=False)
    self.conv_b=Conv2D(1,kernel_size=3,strides=1,padding='same',use_bias=False)

    self.pool_rc=AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(patch_size,patch_size),strides=1)
    self.pool_gc=AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(patch_size,patch_size),strides=1)
    self.pool_bc=AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(patch_size,patch_size),strides=1)
        
    self.bn=BatchNormalization()
    self.sigmoid=Activation('sigmoid')
    self.softmax=Activation('softmax')

  def call(self, input,training=True):
    r,g,b=input[:,:,:,0:1],input[:,:,:,1:2],input[:,:,:,2:3]

    rs=self.conv_r(r)
    gs=self.conv_g(g)
    bs=self.conv_r(b)
    print("rs shape", rs.shape)
    rc=tf.reshape(self.pool_rc(rs),[-1,1])
    gc=tf.reshape(self.pool_gc(gs),[-1,1])
    bc=tf.reshape(self.pool_bc(bs),[-1,1])

    print("rc shape", rc.shape)

    merge=Concatenate(axis=-1)([rc,gc,bc])
    print("merge shaape", merge.shape)
    merge=tf.expand_dims(merge,axis=1)
    print("merge shaape", merge.shape)
    merge=tf.expand_dims(merge,axis=1)
    print("merge shaape", merge.shape)
    merge=self.softmax(merge)
    print("merge shaape", merge.shape)
    merge=tf.repeat(merge,repeats=48,axis=2)
    print("merge shaape", merge.shape)
    merge=tf.repeat(merge,repeats=48,axis=1)
    print("merge shaape", merge.shape)

    r=r*(1+self.sigmoid(rs))
    g=g*(1+self.sigmoid(gs))
    b=b*(1+self.sigmoid(bs))

    output=self.bn(merge[:,:,:,0:1]*r+merge[:,:,:,1:2]*g+merge[:,:,:,2:3]*b,training=training)
    return output
```

Comment: it seems that they are first processing the RGB channels separately, and then they have some sort of attention, like in transformers, but there are no citations on the liked papers about this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.